# Connect Azure databricks to SQL Server with instance name

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am trying to connect databricks to an on premise SQL Server with a non-default instance name.  Before I raise a ticket to investigate it is a firewall issue I wanted to see if my syntax is correct first.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sqlserver_table;

CREATE TABLE sqlserver_table
USING sqlserver
OPTIONS (
  dbtable 'dbo.tablename',
  host 'hostname\INSTANCE01',
  port '56883',
  database 'databasename',
  user 'username',
  password 'password'
);
```

This is the code I'm using in databricks.  When I try to get this to run I get the error message.

> Error in SQL statement: SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host hostnameINSTANCE01, port 56883 has failed

Note that the server is missing the \ between the server name and the instance name.

So I thought maybe the \ needed to be escaped but when I run the above code with servername\instancename I get the following error.

> Error in SQL statement: URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 32: jdbc:sqlserver://servername\INSTANCE01:56883

Any idea what the correct syntax is to connect databricks to a named instance?  I've done some searching but haven't found anything with an instance as of yet.

Comment: you're not supposed to combine port and instance names

Comment: After more than a decade working with sql server I hadn't realised that.  I guess SSMS just ignores one or the other when connecting.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As siggemannen pointed out in the comment one does not need to provide the instance name when providing the port number.  So the corrected code would be.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sqlserver_table;

CREATE TABLE sqlserver_table
USING sqlserver
OPTIONS (
  dbtable 'dbo.tablename',
  host 'hostname',
  port '56883',
  database 'databasename',
  user 'username',
  password 'password'
);
```